# download PDF document from application to local storage and then open with iBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, download

I have a html link on my app called "download instructions pdf"

When I click this I want to download the pdf (stored within the app) to the iPad / iPhone locally and then open it with iBook.

A lot of similar questions mention WebView and use the ViewController, but I have already finished the majority of the app and when I used webview it opens a blank page and the app doesn't run.

This is my first iOS app and I havent used Objective C before so get confused when using the ViewController.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<a href="howtouse.pdf">download instructions pdf</a>
```

This opens the pdf, but as full screen which removes any navigation. So if the user wants to visit another part of the app they must re open the app which isnt user friendly!

I am using xcode 4.6.3
iPad/iPhone simulator 6.1

I been stuck on this for hours, any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What part of the above are you stuck on? What's working, what's not working?

Comment: at the moment I just use <a href="howtouse.pdf">download instructions pdf</a> to open to PDF file in the app, but this removed all navigation on the app. so if the user wants to continue using the app they need to reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the download part, take a look at some [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) samples

After you downloaded the PDF into a NSData, write it to the Documents path which can me found this way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFilename"];
```

For opening it, try UIDocumentInteractionController [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094298/open-saved-pdf-file-in-documents-folder-of-ipad-in-ibooks)

Answer (score 1):

I created an example where UIDocumentInteractionController is used. I uploaded to Github and you can download it here:

https://github.com/cjimenezpacho/openpdfibooks

Basically is this piece of code in a IBAction and the required delegate methods (very similar to link sp4rkbr):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
URLForResource: @"iPhoneintro" withExtension:@"pdf"];
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
self.docController.delegate = self;
[self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Links to Apple documentation:

Class:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html