# How to open Pdf file in different option like as iBook ,Go Daddy etc and save there in iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In one Of my activity I have generated pdf file on WebView and save this file in document folder successfully but this file path show for simulator then get pdf file easily, but when we run my application on iPhone simulator then file show on device successfully and give file path but I can't find file where it save how to get this file open another problem I am using this code.

```
NSMutableData *data2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:byteArray.count];

for (NSNumber *byteVal in self.WebService->byteArray)
{
    Byte b = (Byte)(byteVal.intValue);

    [data2 appendBytes:&b length:1];
}

NSString *resourceToPath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
fileName = [resourceToPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

[data2 writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
NSURLRequest *requestFile = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

UIWebView *webView1=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];

webView1.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight) ;
webView1.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView1.scrollView.scrollEnabled =NO;

[webView1 loadRequest:requestFile];

[self.view addSubview:webView1];
```

for download pdf file I am using this.....

```
-(void)DownloadPdffile
{
    NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePAth = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL filePAth];

    UIDocumentInteractionController *docContr = [UIDocumentInteractionController
                                                 interactionControllerWithURL:url2];
    docContr.delegate=self;
    [docContr presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Using this code I've saved Pdf file in simulator successfully but in iPhone device I can't find where is my Pdf file and then using download pdf then .....this image open....!

[image]

But when I tapped any one of option then my application is closed so tell me how to open pdf in these option and save there also

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you need to refer to your documents folder differently in your `-(void)DownloadPdffile` method.  Like this:

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFilePath [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourPdfFile.pdf];// your yourPdfFile file here
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

docController.delegate = self;
[docController retain];
// docController is released when dismissed (autorelease in the delegate method)

BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:yourReadPdfButton.frame inView:self.view  animated:YES]; // Provide where u want to read pdf from yourReadPdfButton
```

([from Prince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094579/793607))

Comment: how to use this line and what the mean of "yourReadPdfButton" please explain  BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:yourReadPdfButton.frame inView:self.view  animated:YES];

Comment: Ahhh.. the isValid just lets you know if the app was able to display the menu.

Comment: this is right but write this line show ..yourReadPdfButton not exist so ....this object related which????

Comment: sorry again, it can be just any frame on your screen.  The menu will grow out of that frame.